# How do I design a racket a function that takes a list and returns the last positive value of a list. If there's no positive value it returns 'negative

Tags: racket

Needs to be created Using the functions and values cons, first, second, rest, empty, empty?, length, append, list, list-ref, and make-list

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code, asking questions over it. Stack Overflow is not the place to get your homework done for free ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since no looping functions are listed, that means we will have to use recursion to iterate over the list. This can be done by repeatedly calling our function on the list with its first value removed. We also cannot use other function calls to manipulate a variable to store the last positive value we have encountered, so we can instead track it with a parameter passed into the function. This gives us the following function:

```
#lang racket

(define (get-last-positive lastPositive lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) lastPositive]
        [(positive? (first lst)) (get-last-positive (first lst) (rest lst))]
        [else (get-last-positive lastPositive (rest lst))]))

(get-last-positive -1 '(1 -2 2 5 -1 0)) ;example call
```

To explain the code more concretely, if the list is empty we will have found the last positive value if it exists and can return it. If there was no positive value, then -1 will have been passed to `lastPositive` all the way through the call stack. In the second condition, if we have found a positive value, recursively call `get-last-positive` with the that value passed into `lastPositive` and the list without its first value. In the third condition we have not found a positive value, so recursively call `get-last-positive` so do not change the value for `lastPositive` and pass in the rest of the list to be checked.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The allowable Racket Functions and Special Forms are:
define and or not cond else local 
Any equality function such as equal?, symbol=?, etc.
any type predicate such as number?, boolean?, etc.
The list functions and values cons, first, second, rest, empty, empty?, length, append, list, list-ref, and make-list (for testing).
and the question is: Write a function last-positive that consumes a list of numbers and produces the last positive number in the list. If there are no positive numbers in the list, the function produces the symbol 'not-found.

Comment: @Shah I have edited the response to match the functions you've listed. I think it should satisfy the requirements now.

Comment: Idea is correct ... but function requested is `(last-positive lon)`, producing `'not-found` if none, and what about `(last-positive '(0+1i))` ?